# Anchore feed sync issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We deployed anchore containers using podman in linux box by assigning static ip to each contianer. That static ip is within the ip range of the server.
The anchore is integrated with jenkins it is able to scan the image but vulnerabilities are not reporting. When we explored that we identified that feed sync is not happening.
It is throwing the error one or more groups failed to sync.

Anchore version : v1.0.0